# stat probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Okay so $A=0.2, B=0.5$ and the probability that both $A$ and $B$ occur is equal to $0.12$.

What is $P((A \cap B) \cup A^c)$?

What I basically did was $0.12 \times 0.5+0.5+0.2-0.12 = 1.2$.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: *Hints:* A probability cannot be greater than $1$. I recommend drawing a Venn diagram to clarify what calculation you should use. In particular, notice that $A \cap B$ and $A^c$ must be disjoint.

Comment: can you please show me a step by step way. I am confused.

Comment: See my expanded hint below

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The set of all events here is $X$ and hence $P(X) = 1$. We are given that $P(A) = 0.2$ and $P(B) = 0.5$, as well as $P(A\cap B) = 0.12$.

Also, $P(A) + P(A^c) = 1$ and $P(B) + P(B^c) = 1$, as in fact for any set of events $Y \subset X$, we have that the total probability $$P(Y) + P(Y^c) = P(Y \cup Y^c) = P(X) = 1.$$

Now, what is $P((A\cap B)\cup A^c)$ in terms of $P(A), P(B), P(A \cap B)$ or $P(A^c)$?

Comment: is it 0.92? I think thats the right answer

Comment: Yes, as $A\cap B$ and $A^c$ are disjoint, i.e., $(A \cap B)$ and $A^c$ do not intersect, we have that

$$P((A\cap B) \cup A^c) = P(A\cap B) + P(A^c) = P(A\cap B) + (1 - P(A))$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

[image]

You need the yellow part plus the blue part.

BTW, probability is a value between $0$ and $1$ **by definition**, so that rules out your answer.